# How to continuously move an image smoothly in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Yes, I know that there are similar questions out there, and I have read through them, but they do not help me (or most likely I just don't understand them enough to use them).

FYI: I do not use classes, or anything like that.

**The Problem**

So what I am trying to do is make security cameras in my game. It moves/pans the image left until the image reaches the edge, waits like 1 second or something, then it moves/pans the image right until the image reaches the edge, wait 1 second or something, repeats. I have accomplished that, but the resulting animation looks jerky/laggy. I wish to make the animation smoother and less jerky/laggy.

**EDIT: I also want to keep the same speed of the animation if possible**

**Here is my code;**

```
if var_bounce == 0:
    if var_x <= -207:
        if var_x_timer == 10:
            var_x = var_x + 10
            var_bounce = 1
            var_x_timer = 0
        else:
            var_x_timer = var_x_timer + 1
    else:
        var_x = var_x - 10
if var_bounce == 1:
    if var_x >= 0:
        if var_x_timer == 10:
            var_x = var_x - 10
            var_bounce = 0
            var_x_timer = 0
        else:
            var_x_timer = var_x_timer + 1
    else:
        var_x = var_x + 10
```

**Some Variables and Values Explained**

- The `var_x` is the x value which I just place in the x value spot
  when I use the `blit` function.

  E.g. `screen.blit(image, (var_x, 0))`
- The `var_x_timer` is the timer for when it needs to wait for the 1
  second or something.

  The reason why I am using the framerate of my program rather than use
  a timer function because 1) I did not want to sleep/delay/stop the
  program just for this, and 2) I don't need it to be precise when
  waiting.
- The `var_bounce` is just a way for the program to know that it has
  reached the edge and needs to go in the opposite direction.
- The minimum and maximum x values are `0` and `-207`respectively and
  this is so that the image still covers the entire screen. I got these
  values through trial and error, so no need to change those.

**Other/Additional Information**

- The size of my images for the security cameras is `1600 x 718`
- The screen size is `1366 x 718`

**My Code in Action**

*(Ignore the other stuff)*

*(Looped)*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not "move" the image by 10, but move it by 1.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the loop:

```py
var_x, var_bounce, speed_x = 0, 0, 2

# application loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    if var_bounce == 0:
        if var_x > -207:
            var_x = var_x - speed_x 
        else:
            var_bounce = 1
    elif var_bounce == 1:
        if var_x < 0:
            var_x = var_x + speed_x 
        else:
            var_bounce = 0

    # [...]
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background = pygame.Surface((window.get_width()+200, window.get_height()))
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 100, *background.get_size(), (64, 64, 64), (127, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
for rect, color in tiles:
    pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect)

var_x, var_bounce, speed_x = 0, 0, 2

def scroll():
    global var_x, var_bounce
    if var_bounce == 0:
        if var_x > -200:
            var_x = var_x - speed_x
        else:
            var_bounce = 1
    elif var_bounce == 1:
        if var_x < 0:
            var_x = var_x + speed_x
        else:
            var_bounce = 0

run = False
while not run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = True

    scroll()

    window.blit(background, (var_x, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```